# Multiple relative parent directories in visual studio project settings

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, project-settings

I often find that I have problems getting visual studio to find my headers and I think I might have finally found out why: it seems that visual studio does not understand multiple relative directories in project configurations, e.g:

[image]

When that directory certainly does exist.

My question is: can somebody confirm this is the case and, if so, is there a reason why they'd do this? Is it a bug or intentional?

Comment: Does `$(ProjectDir)` finish with a `\`?

Comment: Nope, the contents are:

c:\prog\engine\vs2010project

Comment: So your directory specification is `c:\prog\engine\vs2010project..\..\angle\include`. I think you simply have a missing backslash. (My earlier comment was intended to ask if there is a trailing backslash, the backslash character got lost, apologies.)

Comment: Oops, no sorry. It does have the trailing backslash.
c:\prog\engine\vs2010project\..\..\angle\include

Comment: Ok, scrub this question. The problem was that the project properties pages configuration drop down didn't match the currently active one. It had been reset somehow, which threw me. I'll delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

Posting as an answer as I can't really fit this into a comment although its a bit frowned upon...

The easiest way to debug this is to run Process Monitor from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), and add a filter to only show access to your file name. I made an example c++ project which tried to load a non existant header `#include "Bobby.h"` and then added the following filter to Process Monitor:

`Path    Contains     Bobby.h     Include`

Then I ran the build and got the following output:

```
CreateFile  C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\Bobby.h   NAME NOT FOUND
CreateFile  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\Bobby.h  NAME NOT FOUND
CreateFile  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\atlmfc\include\Bobby.h   NAME NOT FOUND
CreateFile  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\Bobby.h  NAME NOT FOUND
CreateFile  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\Bobby.h  NAME NOT FOUND
CreateFile  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\WinRT\Bobby.h   NAME NOT FOUND
```

From this output you can easily see where the compiler searched for the header file - It may be good enough to help you understand why it didn't find it.

HTH

Comment: Thanks Mike, that is a help. Turns out I was just editing the wrong configuration. I think the currently selected project got changed during a git merge, which threw me. Ah well.